# what is the process of the running the java files that are present in testng xml using ANT

Tags: java, ant, testng

I want to know the process of running the java files that are mentioned in testng.xml using ANT.

Do we have to compile those java files first and then run it? Or the testng ANT task takes care of compiling and running? I have gone through  the testng ANT task code but i didn't quite get it. Can someone explain?

```
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="testng.jar" />

<testng classpathref="run.cp" outputDir="${testng.report.dir}" sourcedir="${test.src.dir}" haltOnfailure="true">

    <xmlfileset dir="${test14.dir}" includes="testng.xml" />
</testng>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [testng doc](http://testng.org/doc/ant.html)

> One of attributes classpath, classpathref or nested  must
>   be used for providing the tests classpath.

Which means you have to compile test classes before running the tests.